# Need help understanding this result

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve a question, where the following result occurs in the solution -

$\sin y \sin(2x+y)=0 \ and \sin x \sin(x+2y)=0$

Then it implies that

1) Either $x=0=y$

2) or $\tan x=\tan y =-\tan(x+y)$  or $x=y=\pi /3$

I understand the first result but not the second. please help me with that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x+2 y=\pi$ and $2 x+y=\pi$

Solve for $x$ and $y$

Comment: should they not be equal to $n\pi$ rather ? as $sin x =0 $  implies that $x=2n\pi$  ?

Comment: @AmanMittal:  sure.  But I was just trying to help you understand the particular solution you posted.

Comment: ok, but why did we consider it just $\pi$ in this case ? this is what i really wanted to know ? is it just that we considered a particular case instead of a general solution ?

Comment: @AmanMittal: that's all, we just considered a special case, likely one of interest.